# Google Adsense code?

Tags: google-adsense

The google adsense code contains a reference to a javascript file. If I have 3 ad units on a single page, can I remove this reference from the other two because it is just the same. Will it violate the "don't manipulate the code" rule of google adsense?

Comment: I can't imagine it would break it, but as you say, it's not a good idea to fiddle with the code Google supplies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to let Google do its thing without manipulating the code.

As this support page mentions, Google will optimize based on your pages:

http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9735

Comment: Well, I thought so!